# Probability density function with squares and triangles

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a square with corners at the points $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$, and $(1,1)$, and we choose a ﬁfth point arbitrarily from inside this square (i.e. both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the ﬁfth point are uniformly distributed over the interval $[0, 1]$). Let $A$ be the area of the triangle with corners at $(0,0), (1,0)$, and the randomly chosen point.

What is the probability density function of $A$?

Can someone help me with some hints?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** the area is a function of $y$ only.

**solution:** the area is $A=y/2$. Hence the density of $A$ is
$$
f(a) = \begin{cases} 2& \text { if } 0\le a\le 1/2 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$